# Fetch data from API, problem first time array is undefined

Tags: angular, get, themoviedb-api

I have a issue fetching data from API, I fetch from API when I submit a form. The issue is when I console  log the array to see what elements I receive, my array is undefined, and it's only when I click (submit the form) the second time that the array contains the data.
I try to console the array in my `submitForm` function in the component movie that you can see I the code.

[image: Screen of my console displaying the issue]

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Subject, Observable, pipe } from "rxjs";
import { Movie } from "../models/movie.model";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
import { TvShow } from '../models/tvShow.models';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class SearchService {
  token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  searchMovie(title): Observable<Movie[]> {
    return this.httpClient
    .get<Movie[]>(
        "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=" +
          this.token +
          "&language=fr&query=" +
          title
      )
      .pipe(map((response: any) => response.results));
  }
}
```

works the second time that I submit the form.

```html
<div class="search">
  <form class="form-inline" [formGroup]="movieForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
    <input type="text" id="title" class="form-control form-control-lg" formControlName="title"
      placeholder="Search for a movie">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="movieForm.invalid">Search</button>
  </form>
</div>
<app-list *ngFor="let movie of movies; let i = index" [indexOfMovie]="i" [movie]="movie">
</app-list>
```

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Movie } from "src/app/models/movie.model";
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
import { SearchService } from "src/app/services/search.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-movie",
  templateUrl: "./movie.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./movie.component.scss"],
})
export class MovieComponent implements OnInit {
  movies: Movie[];
  movieForm: FormGroup;


  constructor(
    private searchService: SearchService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initForm();
  }


  initForm() {
    this.movieForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      title: ["", Validators.required],
    });
  }

  submitForm() {
    const formValue = this.movieForm.value;
    const movieSearch = formValue["title"];

    this.searchService
      .searchMovie(movieSearch)
      .subscribe((res) => (this.movies = res));

    console.log('hello submit')
    console.log(this.movies)
  }
}
```

If someone have ideas, I will be happy!

Comment: This happens because your console’s are outside of your subscribe. Put them inside your subscribe and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are making a asynchronous call using the http client, which means by the time your are running

```
console.log(this.movies)
```

your movies may not be loaded. You can move your console.log inside the subscribe section to see the results.

```
   this.searchService
      .searchMovie(movieSearch)
      .subscribe((res) => {
           this.movies = res;
           console.log(this.movies);
       });
```